# What is the equivalent of Spring's `@Profile` annotation for microprofile?

Tags: spring, microprofile

I'm used to using Spring and have heavily used `@Profile` for different configurations for local/dev/production environments. We've moved to microprofile - is there an equivalent easy way to specify different configurations at runtime with microprofile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Environment](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#environments) with [@Requires](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Requires.html) / [@Requirements](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Requirements.html) , simple example with `env = "foo"`:

**Application.java**:

```java
package helloworld;

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = Micronaut.run(Application.class);
        SomeService someService = context.getBean(SomeService.class);

        someService.doWork();
        Optional<String> someProperty = context.getProperty("some.property", String.class);
        System.out.println("some.property=" + someProperty.get());
    }

}
```

**SomeService.java**:

```java
package helloworld;

public interface SomeService {

    void doWork();

}
```

**SomeServiceFoo.java** for `foo` env:

```java
package helloworld;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Requires(env = "foo")
public class SomeServiceFoo implements SomeService {

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("SomeServiceFoo work");
    }

}
```

**SomeServiceBar.java** for `bar` env:

```java
package helloworld;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Requires(env = "bar")
public class SomeServiceBar implements SomeService {

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("SomeServiceBar work");
    }

}
```

**application-foo.yml** properties for `foo` env

```
some:
  property: some-property-foo
```

**application-bar.yml** properties for `bar` env

```
some:
  property: some-property-bar
```

run application:

```sh
java -Dmicronaut.environments=foo -jar helloworld-0.1.jar
```

application output:

```sh
SomeServiceFoo work
some.property=some-property-foo
```

Also you can setup **Environment** variables `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=bar,bar2`

and take a look at [Cloud Configuration](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/guide/index.html#cloudConfiguration) with already defined [Environment](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/api/io/micronaut/context/env/Environment.html)

P.S. for *IntelliJ IDEA* (Run/Debug Configurations) also setup preferred *Environment variables* `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=bar`