# disable consul configuration in local

Tags: java, microservices, micronaut

I created a simple micronaut app in my local with 'consul-config' feature. My code can able to connect and get properties from consul key/value store. I have below configuration in my bootstrap.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: user-service
config-client:
  enabled: true
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: true
    defaultZone: "${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}:${CONSUL_PORT:8500}"
```

Everything is fine but I don't want to use consul in my local computer, because since it involves the network activity so startup takes sometime. I want to avoid consul in local but I need it in dev, test and prod environments.

I have below code in my app. @Value annotation will try to load 'db-schema' and if it not founds then uses 'local' as default value. So if consul is disabled then my app should use 'local' else it should load values based on consul configuration.

```
@Value("${db-schema:local}")
private String dbSchema;
```

How I can do this with out code changes and only with environment options?

I tried setting VM option '-Dmicronaut.config-client.enabled=false' but still it loads bootstrap.yml and trying to connect consul.

Comment: you can split you application properties, beans by different  environments - local/dev/prod... take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589325/8112217

Comment: This links shows loading beans conditionally but I need all beans in my local except it should not go to consul for configuration.

Comment: not only beans, also property conditionally, for example different properties for your `db-schema`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do it.  One is to create a file like `src/main/resources/application-local.yml` which contains the following:

```
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: false
```

And in your local environment `export MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=local`.

Comment: This is working fine in local with out having src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml file buti f I include it then bootstrap is getting higher precedence and trying to connect consul and ignoring properties in application-local.yml because I need consul in other environments so I can not remove bootstrap.

Comment: You could move `consul.client.registration.enabled` from `bootstrap.yml` to `application.yml` or you could set that to `false` in `bootstrap-local.yml` instead of `application-local.yml`.

Comment: Note that you can't move all Consul related settings to `application.yml`.  For example, if you want to use Consul for distributed config you have to define `micronaut.config-client.enabled` and `consul.client.defaultZone` in `bootstrap.yml`.